# Multiple onion services

Tags: tor-install

[image]

I eventually would like to have multiple onion services running on my from my laptop. Im trying to download tor client not browser on my Librem 14 (debian) and also have apache2 configured .

im trying to follow https ://community.torproject.org/onion-services/setup/install/ but get stumped when i click Enable the Torproject package repository by following the https ://support.torproject.org/apt/tor-deb-repo/ where it tells me to Create a new file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ named tor.list . Add the following entries: ```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg] https: //deb.torproject.org/torproject.org main
deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg] https ://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org main

Now when I went in to make the file it’s all ok . I tried to add data to the file tor.list from the files app and it said it was read only so can the entries be made from the files app or do I need to use command line if so what commands

keyring.gpg] https ://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org main
deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg] https: //deb.torproject.org/torproject.org main

and is it ok to tor.list. Add the following entries:
deb     [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg] https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org  main
deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg] https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org

if i see that it is empty and read only

Comment: It seems that your question is not finished and contains several duplicate lines. Could you please check and correct it?

Comment: I eventually would like to have multiple onion services running from my laptop. Im trying to download tor client not browser on my Librem 14 (debian) and also have apache2 configured . if the tor.list file which i made in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ as instructed by the tor site is and its empty and read only is it ok to add the entries 
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg] https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org main deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg] https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org

Answer (score 0):

You must add apt repositories **and** corresponding signing keys being a root, so just do `sudo -s` and add it from the root user( `#` prompt), type `exit` after you're done. You need to configure as many hidden services as you want just by adding a corresponding lines to your `torrc` and creating directories for them - after that you point their port forwards to your apache2 and that's it!

Comment: the tor.list file which i made in /etc/apt/sources.list.d is read only though and empty even in root when i attempt to add the entries .. is it still ok to try and bypass and proceed ?

Comment: you should write an apt repository description line there - or it will be no use of making any further step. just read it here https://support.torproject.org/apt/

Comment: what is the safest way to change the permissions of this file so that I can can configure tor package repository and add :
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg] https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org < Byzantium> main
deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg] https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org < Bytzantium> main

to tor.list file   .. in another forum i was instructed to change byzantium to bullseye because byzantium isnt supported by tor is it safe to continue with bullseye

Comment: https://forum.torproject.net/t/how-to-edit-my-sources-list-to-add-tor-debian-repository/7319

Comment: **ALL** the source lists must have mode 644 and owned by root:root